# Laravel multi-select form fields reset on request error

Tags: php, forms, laravel, multi-select

I've got a form on a Laravel 5.2 application that uses form request validation. When I submit a request and the validator rejects it it goes back to the form and displays the validator's errors. All the user inputs are still there except for the fields that have multi-select, they are cleared. I don't want them cleared, I want them to display what the user had intended.

I'm having a hell of a time trouble shooting this because my localhost version works fine. This problem only occurs on the production version of the application.

Here is the issue request:

```
class IssueRequest extends Request {

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{   
    $rules = [
        'do' => 'required|date_format:"F d, Y"',
        'issue_advocate' => 'required',
        'issue_type_list' => 'required',
        'file_stale_date' => 'date_format:"F d, Y"',
        'level_of_service_list' => 'required_with:staff_hours',
        'issue_outcome_list' => 'required_with:staff_hours',
        'staff_hours' => 'numeric', 
        'date_closed' => 'date_format:"F d, Y"'

    ];

    return $rules;
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'issue_type_list.required' => 'Please select at least one issue type.',
        'do.required' => 'The date opened field is required.',
        'date_format' => 'The :attribute needs to be in the format "January 1, 2000".',
        'issue_outcome_list.required_with' => 'Please select at least one outcome before entering staff hours (this marks the issue to be closed)',
        'level_of_service_list.required_with' => 'Please select at least one level of service before entering staff hours (this marks the issue to be closed)',
    ];
}

}
```

Here is an excerpt of the form. The fields of concern are the issue_type_list, level_of_service_list and issue_outcome_list:

```
    {!! Form::model($issue, array('method' => 'PATCH',  'url' => 'issues/'.$issue->id)) !!}

@include('issues.addIssueForm')

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('issue_type_list[]', "Issue Type") !!}
{!! Form::select('issue_type_list[]', $issuetypes, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control multi-select', 'id' => 'issue_type']) !!}

@if($errors->first('issue_type_list'))
    <div class="error-item alert alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('issue_type_list') }}</div>
@endif
</div>

{!! Form::hidden('client_id',Input::get('client_id')) !!}


<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('level_of_service_list[]', "Level of Service") !!}
{!! Form::select('level_of_service_list[]', $level_of_service, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control multi-select', 'id' => 'level_of_service']) !!}
</div>

@include('issues.referralForm')

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('issue_outcome_list[]', "Outcome") !!}
{!! Form::select('issue_outcome_list[]', $outcome, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control ']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('staff_hours', "Staff hours") !!}
{!! Form::input('number', 'staff_hours', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'min'=>'0', 'step' => '0.1']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Edit Issue', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    <a href="{{ Request::server('HTTP_REFERER') }}" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Cancel</a>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: can you debug it with IssueRequest replacing with just Request to check whether the contents are passed.also do a dd($request) on the top of the controller method to see the request content.

Comment: Hmmm ok that wasn't the outcome I was expecting, I replaced IssueRequest with Request and after a dd the output was `Request {#309}`. Nothing else. When the form passes the validator things do save to the database properly.